# Why ee.Reducer.sum() and ee.Reducer.mean() get the same value when used in reduceResolution()

Tags: google-earth-engine, resolution

I'd like to reduce Landsat image resolution to MODIS. But when I use sum () and mean() reducer, the results are the same. Then I tried using Minmax, mode reducer, surprisingly, they all are the same. What's wrong? Here are my script and comments.

```
// those are from GEE
// Load a MODIS EVI image.
var modis = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1').first())
    .select('EVI');

// Display the EVI image near La Honda, California.
Map.setCenter(-122.3616, 37.5331, 12);
Map.addLayer(modis, {min: 2000, max: 5000}, 'MODIS EVI');

// Get information about the MODIS projection.
var modisProjection = modis.projection(); // what's the difference betwen .projection() and crs()
print('MODIS projection:', modisProjection);

// Load and display forest cover data at 30 meters resolution.
var forest = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015')
    .select('treecover2000');

print('landsat projection',forest.projection());    
Map.addLayer(forest, {max: 80}, 'forest cover 30 m');

// compare among different reducer///////////////////////
// Get the forest cover data at MODIS scale and projection.
var forestMean = forest
    // Force the next reprojection to aggregate instead of resampling.
    .reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), // mean is 88.31
      maxPixels: 1024
    })
    // Request the data at the scale and projection of the MODIS image.
    .reproject({
      crs: modisProjection
    });
// non of those works to compute class density 
var forestSum = forest
    // Force the next reprojection to aggregate instead of resampling.
    .reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), // sum is 88
      maxPixels: 1024
    })
    // Request the data at the scale and projection of the MODIS image.
    .reproject({
      crs: modisProjection
    });

Map.addLayer(forestSum, {}, 'forest cover sum at MODIS scale'); 

var forestMode = forest

    // Force the next reprojection to aggregate instead of resampling.
    .reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mode(),
      maxPixels: 1024
    })
    // Request the data at the scale and projection of the MODIS image.
    .reproject({
      crs: modisProjection
    });

Map.addLayer(forestMode, {}, 'forest cover mode at MODIS scale');

var forestMinMax = forest
    // Force the next reprojection to aggregate instead of resampling.
    .reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
      maxPixels: 1024
    })
    // Request the data at the scale and projection of the MODIS image.
    .reproject({
      crs: modisProjection
    });

Map.addLayer(forestMode, {}, 'forest cover minmax at MODIS scale');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A few things that might be useful:

1. Right now when you try to load MinMax to the map you're still loading Mode, if you fix that they do look different.
2. Adjusting your layer visualization parameters might help here I adjusted the layers to "stretched 100%" and they looked better. Otherwise might be worth printing out some layer info to see what's going on.
3. I did have this issue with mean vs. sum in another project and the thing I did to resolve it was to define a resolution, then reduce resolution, then reproject to a defined reduced resolution after. Like:

```
var lsProj = forest.projection();
var forestProj = forest.reproject(lsProj, null, 30); //30m is the landsat resolution

var forestSum = forestProj.reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), // sum is 88
      maxPixels: 65535
    })
    // Request the data at the scale and projection of the MODIS image.
    .reproject(modisProjection, null, 500); //500m is the modis resolution
```